# LibGDX . draw multiline text

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am trying to write a big text using BitmapFont in libGDX . But it shows on one line and the user can see only the first part of the text . How can I make that bitmapFont made new line automatically and show whole text on the screen ?

Comment: Do you want it to jump to next line automatically when no more space is available?

Comment: yes . shall I use \n ?

Comment: Either use \n for manual new lines (font.drawMultiline) or use font.drawWrapped with a wrapwidth to do it automatically.

Comment: @noone nice to learn of `bitmapFont.drawWrapped()`, this method is extremely useful.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Either use `\n` for manual new lines and render the font via [`font.drawMultiLine(...)`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/BitmapFont.html#drawMultiLine-com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Batch-java.lang.CharSequence-float-float-).

Or use [`font.drawWrapped(...)`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/BitmapFont.html#drawWrapped-com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Batch-java.lang.CharSequence-float-float-float-) with a wrap width to let libgdx wrap it automatically (manually added `\n` are still supported).

**Update:**
 With libGDX 1.6 the [draw methods were enhanced](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/pull/2955), and there is no further need for drawMultiLine and drawWrapped, so those were removed. Draw methods can handle multiple lines and a new [boolean wrap](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/BitmapFont.html#draw-com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Batch-java.lang.CharSequence-float-float-float-int-boolean-) parameter was introduced.

Comment: Seems there is no font.drawMultiLine(...)/font.drawWrapped(...) methods anymore in latest libgdx versions. How to write multiline text now?

Comment: now you can simply use font.draw(...) and \n where you want to have a new line

Answer (score 6):

If you take a look at the docs, you'll see that you can use the same `font.draw` function, except now you're passing the target location width and whether to wrap or not.

```
draw(Batch batch, java.lang.CharSequence str, float x, float y, float targetWidth, int halign, boolean wrap)
```