# Line break in font.draw

Tags: java, libgdx

Currently I'm using

```
font.draw(batch, "In Year:"+year, 0, 100);
```

But I want `year`in another line.
I've already tried things like `\n` and `\r\n` but it doesn't effect the outcome at all.

I'm a newbie to programming, so I don't know how to do it in another way. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: `font` is the libGDX BitmapFont I'm using

Comment: @MuratK. it's the BitmapFont I'm using

Comment: You mean libgdx's `BitmapFont`? If so you should state that in your question.

Comment: @Thomas As I said, I'm a newbie so I'm not quite sure what uses what and stuff...

Comment: Using a library/framework like libgdx requires some effort in setup etc. so you should know whether you're using it or not. And if you're not sure then post the fully qualified class name, e.g. `com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont` so that we at least have a chance of what you're using.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25442287/libgdx-draw-multiline-text According to the answers manually adding a line break should work so either you're using an older version of libgdx or have some other issues in your configuration or code.

Comment: @Thomas okay thanks for the advice

Comment: @Thomas haha thanks thats what I needed. Seems like my libGDX is a little out of date